# How to group two columns and multiply other two into a new column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm importing the following .xlsx file into a dataframe.

```
dfMenu = pd.read_excel("/Users/FoodTrucks.xlsx")
```

| Price | Quantity | FoodTruck | FoodTruck_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.00 | 10 | Burgers | 1 |
| 1.20 | 50 | Tacos | 2 |
| 0.60 | 30 | Tacos | 2 |
| 1.12 | 40 | Drinks | 4 |
| 2.00 | 20 | Burgers | 1 |

My goal is to show the total revenue for each food truck with its ID and name in a new column, called "Revenue".

I am currently trying to use the code below, but I'm struggling with the multiplication of the columns "Price" and "Quantity" into a new one and grouping "FoodTruck" and "FoodTruck_ID" in an elegant way.

```
df = df.groupby((['FoodTruck', 'FoodTruck_ID'])(df['Revenue'] = df['Price'] * q9['Quantity']))
```

I am getting a syntax error *"SyntaxError: cannot assign to subscript here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?"*

What would be the most elegant way to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to first calculate Price*Quantity before doing the groupby:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Price': [3.0, 1.2, 0.6, 1.12, 2.0],
    'Quantity': [10, 50, 30, 40, 20],
    'FoodTruck': ['Burgers', 'Tacos', 'Tacos', 'Drinks', 'Burgers'],
    'FoodTruck_ID': [1, 2, 2, 4, 1]
})

df['Revenue'] = df['Price']*df['Quantity']

df.groupby(['FoodTruck','FoodTruck_ID'])['Revenue'].sum()
```

Output

```
FoodTruck  FoodTruck_ID
Burgers    1               70.0
Drinks     4               44.8
Tacos      2               78.0
Name: Revenue, dtype: float64
```